# React MenuItem Custom CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am using a DropdownButton and MenuItem combination for generating a drop down.
How can i change the alignment of the menuItem

I want to generate a Horizontal dropdown instead of vertical. Below CSS can make the dropdown horizontal but I'm not able to apply this in react code.

```
left-flyout {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Below is an example of horizontal dropdown using ul and li.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpLa33ad/39/

My drop down structure looks like below.

```
<Nav bsStyle
<DropdownButton>
<MenuItem className='dropdown-menu'> </MeniItem>
</DropdownButton>
</Nav>
```

I tried using the below CSS modification in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method , but the dropdown is still showing up vertical instead of horizontal.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu-left')[0].style['position'] = 'absolute !important';
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu-left')[0].style['top'] = '0';
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu-left')[0].style['left'] = '200px';
```

Comment: dont use javascript for this. use css. Put a class on the parent.. call it `horizontal`. Then use a stylesheet with css to change the styles

Comment: You mean like  <MenuItem style={position: 'absolute !important';top: '0';left: '40%';width: '120px';margin: '10px'} >

Comment: no I mean like `<div className="horizontal-nav"><Nav>.... </Nav></div>` and in CSS `.horizontal-nav .whatever-the-menuitem-class-is { styles here }`